# MIME type error while importing .vue file

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm new to Vue.js and I got this error while trying to import a .vue file:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="MAIN"></div>
  <script type="importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "vue": "https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.4/dist/vue.esm-browser.js"
      }
    }
  </script>
  <script type="module">
    import { createApp } from 'vue';
    import MyComponent from './library.vue';

    const app = createApp(MyComponent);
    app.mount('.MAIN');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

For more information, I'm using Electron Forge while trying to do this.